# Why were the cabin lights turned on during the flight?

Tags: safety, aircraft-lighting

I was on a flight last night that the Captain came on and said in three minutes we all had to be in seats and buckled due to severe storms we had to fly through. After about five minutes and until we landed-approximately 20 minutes the interior lights were turned on.  This has never happened on a flight I have been on. Was it so we could not see what was going on outside?  There was tons of lightning and clouds.

Comment: Probably to make sure your eyes were adjusted to bright light, to prevent temporary flash blindness from the lightning. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_blindness

Comment: [Related question for the opposite (having lights off during takeoff/landing)](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8471/1696)

Comment: I'd guess that to allow cabin crewto act efficiently if bad things happen.

Comment: Basically to reduce the time taken by eyes to adjust to outside daylight in case of an accident or mishap.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely to keep the passengers awake and alert in the even to severe air turbulence, unusual attitudes, or even a mishap which might be encountered during the passage through those areas of storms.  Awake and alert passengers can better react and avoid injuring themselves and/or others.

It's the nice form of the captain coming on the intercom and saying:

"Good evening ladies and gentlemen.  We are about to pass through an area containing several red cells, possibly hail, and severe turbulence.  If you don't feel like having your head put through an overhead bin, wake up and get those seat belts fastened - NOW!"