# Why are passengers requested to close their window blinds during a night-time takeoff?

Tags: takeoff, windows

Why are passengers requested to close their window blinds during a night-time takeoff?

I understand why they are asked to open them during day-time take-offs and landings - probably because rescue teams can look inside in the case of a crash. But what´s the point in closing them at night?

The only reason I can think of is that people might mistake the cabin lights for landing lights, hence misjudging the planes orientation. Still, it is very difficult to mistake a row of cabin lights for landing lights?

Comment: this questions stands on the assumption that closing the blinds during nighttime is mandatory. where is this claim made?

Comment: As I pilot nothing above UL, I can´t cite the regulation. I can just report from my experience of flights in Europe and Asia, where the Stewardess were quite serious about the issue.

Comment: On every nighttime flight I have been on, the window blinds have actually had to be open, and on most flights the lights dimmed. This makes sense because in an emergency evacuation at night you want you eyes to be already adjusted to the darkness. Also, having the window blinds open means you can see if it is safe to open the exit door. I have never heard of the blinds being closed for takeoff.

Comment: @Ben exactly my point, as also said in another question around here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1536 Never heard of blinds being requested to be shut.

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy I have taken many flights in Europe and Asia and have never seen the blinds closed.  Always open.  Please can you quote an airline>

Comment: I second this, never closed, always open! For Safety!

Comment: Well, I experienced what the OP had. On flights starting around 9-10pm from USA going to Asia, passengers are told to close the blinds. The reason I can think of is that most of the people will sleep (as it's their night time), but the airplane will enter in day light shortly (in just 4-5 hours as opposed to people's 8-9 hours' night). When this happens, very bright sunlight will start entering the airplane, but most passengers are still sleeping. So keeping the blinds down makes sense.

Comment: @farhan, was that during take off or once the plane was in the air?

Comment: @FreeMan In my experiences, it was well after the takeoff. After takeoff, flight attendants gave us something to drink, then dinner and desserts. Then they sang lullabies and gently tucked us in. Oh wait a minute, maybe the last part only happened in my imagination.

Comment: @Farhan the question did specifically address take-off. Perhaps you were too far off in your daydream about the cute stew to notice?  ;)

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy at which airport(s) and with which airline(s) did this occur?

Answer (score 4):

*This is a personal experience rather than an authoritative answer, but I thought it would be relevant.*

I fly a few airlines fairly frequently and have done for many years. I've always thought that blinds should be open for safety reasons. However, a few years back I was on a flight with an airline that I'd flown many times before and had always enforced the blinds-open policy. To my surprise everyone was asked to close the window blinds. Within a year the trend had increased to point where all flights by this airline were blinds-closed. Then, a year or so after that, the policy was reverted to blinds-open and has remained since.

*My theory* is that someone in the senior crew, or crew training, mixed up the policy and started enforcing the wrong one (i.e. blinds-closed). I think this is plausible as the reasons for having blinds-open are not entirely obvious. It would also explain the gradual adoption of the new policy. I guess someone eventually realised the mistake, hence the sudden reversal.

Sorry for the long post and lack of sources. Will delete if deemed not helpful.

Comment: I've flown a lot over the years with several different airlines and I've had once or twice years ago where they required the blinds to be closed. Other than those few times I've never encountered this.