# Is there any country that requires window blinds to be open for takeoff and landing?

Tags: faa-regulations, airliner, easa-regulations, regulations, caa-uk-regulations

Does *any* country legally require the window blinds to be open for takeoff and landing? I'm asking about legal regulations that specifically mention window blinds, not airline procedures or general 'follow the crew instructions' regulations.

I only need one example, whether it's FAA, EASA, a national CAA or some other regulator, or an ICAO standard or recommendation.

Comment: welcome to aviation.SE. As seen [previously](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1536), there seem to be no regulation and it really depends on the airline internal SOP. What makes you think that there is a regulation?

Comment: The airline's policy says if it is necessary or not. As far as I know, there is no regulation for this, and it is used according to the safet y procedures adopted by the company.

Comment: Very related: [Why do we open the window shades during landing and take-off?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8849/why-do-we-open-the-window-shades-during-landing-and-take-off/8853#8853) (on skeptics.se)

Comment: I agree that the "potential dupe" is very related and addresses the situation. However, it only addresses FAA-land, while this question asks about other regulations. Perhaps if we reference the other question for FAA (as has been done), then edit out the FAA portion, this becomes a legitimate, non-dupe, question? It might have the exact same answer, but it does address the other regulatory bodies that way.

Comment: There is a regulation which indirectly covers it.  Certainly in the UK and I'm pretty sure in the US and EASA land, it is an offence to not comply with the lawful instruction of a member of the crew.  Therefore, if you are asked to raise the blinds, it is a legal requirement for you to do so.

Comment: @Simon: For sake of precision only, I assume you are not required to raise the blinds, you may help if you want (but you are not an employee of the airline, it may be against your religion, you may not understand, or your hearing aid may be off, or whatever hypocritical you can think of). I assume the offence comes if you lower the blinds when requested not to do it.

Comment: @mins.  Nope, it's exactly what it says.  Failing to comply with an instruction which is not itself illegal is an offence.  Rarely used but it has been.  Usually, the cabin crew will just mark you down as "idiot" and do it themselves.  But, if it is clear that you understand and that you are able to comply, you might be removed from the flight and prosecuted.  Generic laws like this, e.g. "dangerous driving" are there to provide for reasonable action when a specific law does not apply. Not raising the blinds when instructed is, quite simply, an offence in the UK.

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for the explanation. Interesting.

Comment: To add to what @Simon said, if it is in the Airline's operating procedures, they must also legally follow them (at least in the FAA world). I've seen many civil actions against airlines/employees for failure to follow procedure that had no other regulatory requirement.

Comment: @Simon that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a regulation which indirectly covers it. Certainly in the UK and I'm pretty sure in the US and EASA land, it is an offence to not comply with the lawful instruction of a member of the crew. Therefore, if you are asked to raise the blinds, it is a legal requirement for you to do so.

Failing to comply with an instruction which is not itself illegal is an offence. Rarely used but it has been. Usually, the cabin crew will just mark you down as "idiot" and do it themselves. But, if it is clear that you understand and that you are able to comply, you might be removed from the flight and prosecuted. Generic laws like this, e.g. "dangerous driving" are there to provide for reasonable action when a specific law does not apply.

A valid defence would be to demonstrate that you were unable to comply to the extent that the prosecution is unable to convince a jury of your peers to find you guilty "beyond reasonable doubt".

So, in summary, albeit indirectly, it is a legal requirement for you to raise the blind when asked to do so in the UK.

Comment: "[I'm not asking about] airline procedures or general 'follow the crew instructions' regulations."

Comment: @J.Hougaard Ah, got it.  To be honest, I hadn't re-read the question after the edit.  Want me to delete?