# Can passengers use headphones during takeoff and landing?

Tags: safety, passenger, easa-regulations

On a recent flight from KBP to KIV operated by Ukraine International Airlines (aircraft B737-800) I was asked by the flight attendant to remove my headphones both during takeoff and landing.

Is this common practice because I never saw it happen on other flights?  Are there any EASA regulations regarding this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the passenger aspects of travel and would be more appropriate on [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RonBeyer possibly, but it seems related to other questions we have here like [Why open up the window shades before takeoff and landing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1536/1696)

Comment: @RonBeyer It depends on why they ask.  If this is in regards to operational regulations, it's legitimate.  If it's in regards to airline policy, it's better to be on Travel.SE.  Though if it is in regards to regualations, the OP needs to add a tag for the governing body they are asking about.  I assume it's EASA?

Comment: @RonBeyer In fact, I just went head and edited it myself, I'm pretty sure it's what the OP meant.  If the OP disagrees, they are welcome to revert it :).

Comment: [Ukraine is not part of EASA](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/international-cooperation/easa-by-country/countries/ukraine), but a partner, meaning there are [bilateral agreements](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Working%20Arrangement%20between%20EASA%20and%20SAAU_EN.pdf). The regulating agency for Ukrainian airspace and Ukrainian registered aircraft is the [State Aviation Administration of Ukraine](http://ias.avia.gov.ua/daai_portal/) (SAAU).

Comment: I am pretty confident it is common practice to tell passengers to not use *anything* during take-off and landing and the purpose is to have everybody pay attention in case something goes wrong. I don't know whether it is a regulation though.

Answer (score 4):

Jan Hudec was right.

Passengers are not to wear headphones during critical phases of the flight (understand : takeoff, landing, taxi, emergencies), because this could prevent them to hear announcements or directions made by the crew in case of emergency, and because headset cables could create an obstruction in case of an evacuation.

Also, this would prevent them from listening to the safety briefing.

This safety rule is enforced, as far as I know, by several European airlines.

Comment: Is there an actual rule you can cite somewhere that says this?